# java frame reprint not working

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class sample {

    JTextField field=new JTextField(10);
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    String message;

    public sample()
    {
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        field.setEditable(true);
        JButton button=new JButton("press here");
        ActionListener listener=new action();
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        panel.add(field);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);

    }

    public void getMessage()
    {
        JTextField f=new JTextField(10);
        f.setText(message);
        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        p.add(f);
        frame.add(p);
        frame.repaint();  <-- problem here
    }

    class action implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            message=field.getText();
            frame.remove(panel);
            getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

//The problem is frame doesn't call repaint method at getMessage method. So, I have to minimize the window to solve this problem. Is their any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you added a component to a visible GUI. By default all components have a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

What you really need to do is invoke the layout manager so the size/location of the component can be determined.

The basic code should be:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager
panel.repaint(); // to repaint components
```

In JDK7 and later you can also do the revalidate()/repaint() on the frame.